# IONIC 2 - WordPress post new user request after getting nonce token from server

Tags: wordpress, angular, ionic2

I am using wp-json-api plugin at my WordPress endpoint and this requires me to send a nonce token along with user information to register a new user. To get a nonce token I need to make a GET request first and then after getting the token I can POST user data for registration.

Below is the function I have created to get the nonce token:-

```
public getRegistrationNonce () {
    let nonceurl = this.config.wordpressApiBaseUrl + '/api/get_nonce/?controller=user&method=register';
    return this.http.get(nonceurl)
    .map(result => {
        return result.json();
    }); 
}
```

I am not sure how to return the token data to my registration function that POSTs the data required for registration.

The registration function is given below:-

```
public register(data) {

    let token = this.getRegistrationNonce();        
    data.push({'nonce' :token}); 
    let registrationurl = this.config.wordpressApiBaseUrl + '/api/user/register';
    return this.http.post(registrationurl, data)
    .map(result => {
        return result.json();
    });    
}
```

Please show me how I can achieve this.

Comment: Are you sure you can use 'Nonce' for external applications? I think you should be using oAuth.

Comment: As this plugin describes the Method: register, I was looking to create that solution https://wordpress.org/plugins/json-api-user/other_notes/ . Do you think it is possible with this plugin?

Comment: Check my answer. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my understanding you have to create a service for these function. You can all it **Auth**.

Before you do everything, check you have installed https://wordpress.org/plugins/json-api/ because the plugin you have mentioned depends on it. And then you have enable '**User**' controller in **Wordpress -> Setting -> JSON API**.

Then let's come to your Ionic application Auth service
It might look something like this

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable()
  export class Auth {

  token: any;
  status: any;

  constructor(public http: Http) {

  }
}
```

Then add your functions.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable()
  export class Auth {

    token: any;
    status: any;

    constructor(public http: Http) {

    }

    getRegistrationNonce() {
        let nonceurl = this.config.wordpressApiBaseUrl + '/api/get_nonce/?controller=user&method=register';

        this.http.get(nonceurl)
            .map(result => 
                result.json();
            )
            .subscribe(data => {
                this.token = data;
                /** I have checked the returned data and it will be like 
                    {
                       "status": "ok",
                       "controller": "user",
                       "method": "register",
                       "nonce": "531604a95d"
                    }

                  **/
            });
    }

    register(data) {

        this.getRegistrationNonce();
        let registrationurl = this.config.wordpressApiBaseUrl + '/api/user/register';
        this.http.get(registrationurl + '/?username=' + YOUR USERNAME + '&email=' + YOUR EMAIL + '&nonce=' + this.token.nonce + '&display_name='+YOURNAME+'&notify=both')
            //If your site doesn't have SSL/HTTPS you will have to add another parameter '&insecure=cool' at the end of the string
            .map(result => {
                result.json();
            })
            .subscribe(data => {
                this.status = data;
                /*
                  This will be in a format like,
                  {
                      "status": "ok",
                      "cookie": "a big string",
                      "user_id": 5
                  }
                */
            });
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed answer. WordPress configuration is already setup. Just one question I have, how will it ensure calling getRegistrationNonce function before we call register function.

Comment: In my code, now nothing is getting called. If you want to call a nonce on App startup, you can put the code inside constructor. Like this.getRegistrationNonce(); Let me update my answer

Comment: Yeah it can be used under constructor but I want it to generate a token only when registration function is called so I think I should call it inside the registration function. Just for correction - your .subcribe is missing 's'. will give error so edit it just in case someone copied like me :)

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. I have corrected myself and I have updated answer :)

Comment: If you find my answer helpful please upvote and select it as an answer :)

Comment: yeah will be for sure, just trying to implement your codes with mine. I am not sure what making this.token = data; to undefined. also tried to write in console and it shows undefined but the chrome developer tool shows return data for the request.

Comment: Do you receive any Access-Control-Allow-Origin error?

Comment: no such error and I think there is issue with assigning return data with subscribe data variable. Chrome developer tool network tab shows desired response from server..

Comment: not sure why but changing .map(result => { result.json(); }) to .map(result =>  result.json(); ) Thanks for your help.

Comment: Ah cool. Sorry for not able to reply you on time since I am at work. Glad I could help. :)